# Вопрос по Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

В строке 17(код ниже) я пытаюсь взять координату x и y курсора мышки использую event.x event.y, но выдаётся ошибка, если я нажимаю на окно:'hi' object has no attribute 'x':

```
from tkinter import *
import time
tk=Tk()
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost',1)
tk.resizable(0,0)
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=700,height=525,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.title('GAME')
tk.update()
class hi():
        def __init__(self,canvas):
                self.canvas=canvas
                self.id=self.canvas.create_polygon(15,0, 0,15, 10,30, 10,40, 0,50, 10,45, 0,70, 15,50, 30,70, 20,45, 30,50, 20,40, 20,30, 30,15, fill='green')
                self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>',self.hit)

        def hit(event,self):
                if event.x>pos[0] and event.x<pos[2] and event.y>pos[1] and event.x<pos[3]:#ТУТ
                        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id,fill='red')
                        tk.update()
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id,fill='green')
                        tk.update()

obj=hi(canvas)
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, почему вашему предыдущему вопросу сменили заголовок?

Comment: Здравствуйте, понял, принял

Comment: нет, не понял. Речь о совершенно бессмысленном заголовке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте `def hit(event,self):` на `def hit(self, event):`. Специальное слово "self" всегда должно идти первым аргументом.

Comment: Немного поправлю: self - это не специальное (не зарезервированное) слово. Первый аргумент метода может называться как угодно, независимо от его имени в него придет ссылка на экземпляр класса.